# React Native Navigation, how do you pass and use Props between Class Components?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

export default class LoginScreen extends React.component{

```
render () {
     return (
         <Button = {()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {number: 5} />
      )
}
```

}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render(){
         return(
            {this.props}
            // I would like to display the number passed
         )
    }
}

Comment: please provide a proper code snippet

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, thank you so much for the help. To display I used {this.props.route.params.name}

Answer (score 0):

**Initialise:**-

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
```

**Retrieve data:-**

```
console.log(this.params.name);
console.log(this.params.about);
```

If you are showing in any element, you also show like

```
<Text>{this.params.name}</Text>
```

Here is the complete example code. Maybe it will help you to understand it

https://www.google.com/amp/s/aboutreact.com/react-native-pass-value-from-one-screen-to-another-using-react-navigation/amp/

Comment: I appreciate your help,I cant understand why your solution does not work with mine.

Comment: i appreciate your help, I tried the one above but I have an error saying "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.state.params' . if i console.log(this.props) i have a long object with a name: 'Paul' but I am just not able to display the name.

Comment: I also JSON.stringify(this.props) and it shows the object but I still cant display the name itself by this.props.name or any other way. thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/aboutreact.com/react-native-pass-value-from-one-screen-to-another-using-react-navigation/amp/

Check this link you will get complete solve example

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the answer. this worked for me . {this.props.route.params.name}